# "ImportError: cannot import name QtCore" or any other module from PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I recently downloaded PyQt5 from GitHub and put it in my python2.7 `dist_packages`, but when I do

`>> import PyQt5`

`>> from PyQt5 import QtCore`

I get

> ImportError: cannot import name QtCore

I get this same error when I try to import any module from PyQt5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pyqt5, unlike some package where setup.py does nothing useful, isn't a package you can download from GitHub and copy-paste into your folder, there is a lot of setup and local configurations needed to take place. You'll need to run `python setup.py install`; or use `pip install pyqt5` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently downloaded PyQt5 from GitHub and put it in my python2.7 `dist_packages`

That's your problem. That's not the right way to install packages in Python. A small number of packages happen to work that way, but in general, you have to unpack what you downloaded, then go into the unpacked directory in your terminal/DOS prompt/etc., and run `python setup.py install`.

Or, much more simply, you can usually just do this:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

---

For more information see [Installing PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) in the PyQt5 docs and [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) in the Python docs.